# AJAX me envia datos vacios hacia PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Sucede que  estoy creando una tabla temporal, los datos que voy registrando en la misma los voy pasando a un array (miArray) en js para despues poderlos enviar por medio de AJAX a un PHP y poderlos guardar a una base de datos.
Function del Javascript

```js
function guardardatos(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(miArray));
    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(miArray);
    $.ajax({
      url:'Conexion/Guardar.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:myJsonString,
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
    }).fail(function(resp){
      console.log(resp.responseText);
    });
  }
```

la variable myJsonString los datos que la componen son del array que habia indicado. Cuando lo muestro por consola me da este resultado

```
[{"idarticulo":1,"cantidad":"12","nombre":"AZUCAR BLANCO","precio":"0.30","resultado":3.6}]
```

lo comprobe en una pagina para verificar si se encontraba en la sintaxis correcta de json y me indicaba que si.

El problema radica que cuando se va a pasar a la pagina `Guardar.php` y realizar un `echo json_encode($_POST);` me retorna por consola que el array se encuentra vacio. ¿Alguna idea de porque no esta pasando los datos hacia mi PHP?

El PHP donde se encuentra la pagina de la tabla:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <?php require_once("Vista/Head.php");
          require_once("validarsession.php");
          require_once("Conexion/Conexion.php");
    ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php require_once("Vista/Header.php");?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header" style="text-align:center;">Realizar Compras</h1>
        </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 table-responsive">
          <div class="panel panel-default panel-table panel-success">
            <div class="panel-heading">

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Datos del producto</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row" style="padding:20px;">
                      <label for="">Busqueda:</label>
                      <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow  form-control" data-live-search="true" title="------" id="producto">
                        <?php
                          $class = new conexion();
                          $var = $class->CargarArticulos();
                          foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
                            echo "<option  value=".$value['IDARTICULO'].">".$value['ARTNOMB']."</option>";
                          }
                        ?>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row" style="padding:20px;">
                      <label for="">Cantidad:</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type='text' onKeyPress='return soloNumeros(event)' id="cantidad"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                      <div class="col-md-6"><input type="button" name="" value="Agregar" class="form-control btn btn-success" onclick="Cargar()"></div>
                      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4>Detalle Carro de compras</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row table-responsive" style="padding:20px;">
                      <form class="" action="" id="form_insert">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-fixed display table-responsive table-condensed" id="miTabla">
                          <thead>
                            <th scope="col" style="display:none;"><center>IDARTICULO</center></th>
                            <th scope="col"><center>Cantidad</center></th>
                            <th scope="col"><center>Nombre</center></th>
                            <th scope="col"><center>Precio Cost.</center></th>
                            <th scope="col"><center>Precio Total</center></th>
                            <th scope="col"><center>Accion</center></th>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody id="tablita">

                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                          <div class="col-md-6"><input type="button" name="" value="Comprar" class="form-control btn btn-success" onclick="guardardatos()"></div>
                          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <?php require_once("Vista/Footer.php"); ?>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

y el Javascript que utilizo para llenar la tabla e ir almacenando los resultado:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 var miArray = [];
  function Cargar(){
      var _producto = document.getElementById("producto").value;
      var _cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
      var select = document.getElementById("producto"), //El <select>
       value = select.value, //El valor seleccionado
       text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerText; //El texto de la opción seleccionada
      var _encontradoResultado=false;
        //realizamos el recorrido solo por las celdas que contienen el código, que es la primera
        $("#miTabla tr").find('td:eq(2)').each(function () {
              codigo = $(this).html();
               if(codigo==text){
                    _encontradoResultado=true;
               }
        })
        if (!_producto == "" && _encontradoResultado == false) {
          $.ajax({
            url:'Conexion/Buscar.php',
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:'IDARTICULO='+_producto
          }).done(function(resp){
            var fila;
            for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
              var flotante = parseFloat(resp[i].Precio*_cantidad);
              var resultado = Math.round(flotante*100)/100;
              fila ="<tr><td align='center' style='display:none;    '>"+resp[i].IDARTICULO+"</td> <td align='center'>"+_cantidad+"</td> <td align='center'>"+resp[i].ARTNOMB+"</td> <td align='center'>"+resp[i].Precio+"</td> <td align='center'>"+resultado+"</td> <td align='center'><input type='button' class='borrar btn btn-danger' value='Eliminar' /></td></tr>";
              miArray.push({idarticulo: resp[i].IDARTICULO, cantidad:_cantidad,nombre:resp[i].ARTNOMB,precio:resp[i].Precio,resultado:resultado});
            }
            var btn = document.createElement("TR");
            btn.innerHTML=fila;
            document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
          });
        }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: Podrías compartir tu código PHP?

Comment: Veo que el PHP que compartiste no incluye el fragmento de código que te genera un error. Sin embargo creo que hay un error en la lógica con la que estás plantenado el tema. La función AJAX es una función que realiza un proceso y devuelve una respuesta. En este caso, no veo cuál sería la respuesta que te devolvería a la función.
No se cuál es el archivo PHP que debería procesar el pedido y devolver el resultado.

Comment: El problema es que no estás planteando bien el código. Lo que mandas por `data` debe tener una clave, por ejemplo: `data: {json: myJsonString},` Luego en PHP tendrás el JSON en la clave `json` de `$_POST`. Otra cosa es que si quieres obtener el JSON en PHP debes usar `json_decode`. Finalmente, plantea la pregunta basándote en la realidad del código. Es decir, recupera el JSON con `$_POST["json"]`, haz lo que tengas que hacer con los datos y devuelve algo a Ajax, un mensaje de éxito o error por ej. No plantees una pregunta en la que intentas devolver lo mismo que envías, eso no tiene  sentido.

Answer (score 1):

detallando un poco la primera parte creo que si envías esto `[{"idarticulo":1,"cantidad":"12","nombre":"AZUCAR BLANCO","precio":"0.30","resultado":3.6}]` lo mas seguro es que no te va a funcionar porque estas enviando un objeto en la posicion *0* deberias enviar unicamente el json asi: `{"idarticulo":1,"cantidad":"12","nombre":"AZUCAR BLANCO","precio":"0.30","resultado":3.6}`;

**SOLUCION ACEPTADA**

> Debido a la aclaración de que queria enviar varios json al servidor se dejo la siguiente respuesta

```
     var myJsonString = {}; 
     miArray.forEach(function(v,k){myJsonString[k]=JSON.stringify(v)});
     $.ajax({
      url:'Conexion/Guardar.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:myJsonString,
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
    }).fail(function(resp){
      console.log(resp.responseText);
    });
```

ahora si lo muestra con `var_dump($_POST);` en el archivo php

**SOLUCION PRPUESTA**

```
para solucionarlo solo debes hacer esto 

    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(miArray[0]);
     $.ajax({
      url:'Conexion/Guardar.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:{"json":myJsonString},
      dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
    }).fail(function(resp){
      console.log(resp.responseText);
    });
```

ahora si lo muestra con `echo $_POST["json"];` en el archivo php

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82446/discussion-on-answer-by-junior-ajax-me-envia-datos-vacios-hacia-php).